# How to split code and date from List in python?

Tags: python

I got a python program with a list of codes and dates in it. For example, the list below has code and date in it.

```
List = ['10', '11', '11', '12', '2018-06-19 00:00:00', '2018-06-20 23:59:59']
```

I want to split the code and date separately into two different list List_code which will have all the code and List_Date which will have all the dates, as shown bellow.

```
List_Code = ['10', '11', '11', '12']
List_Date = ['2018-06-19 00:00:00', '2018-06-20 23:59:59']
```

How can I achieve this?
Thanks.

Comment: What criteria are you using to tell what goes in `List_Code` and what goes in `List_Date`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you codes are composed of digits only, then use `str.isdigit` to filter them.

```
lst = ['10', '11', '11', '12', '2018-06-19 00:00:00', '2018-06-20 23:59:59']

list_code = [x for x in lst if x.isdigit()]
# list_code:  ['10', '11', '11', '12']

list_date = [x for x in lst if not x.isdigit()]
# list_date ['2018-06-19 00:00:00', '2018-06-20 23:59:59']
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a regular expression to match date strings:

```
import re

List = ['10', '11', '11', '12', '2018-06-19 00:00:00', '2018-06-20 23:59:59']

def isDate(s):
    return True if re.match('\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}', s) else False

# Date strings:
List_Date = [x for x in List if isDate(x)]
# ['2018-06-19 00:00:00', '2018-06-20 23:59:59']

# Other strings:
List_Code = [x for x in List if not isDate(x)]
# ['10', '11', '11', '12']
```